# How can I list files of a directory in Rust?

Tags: rust

How can I list all the files of a directory in Rust? I am looking for the equivalent of the following Python code.

```
files = os.listdir('./')
```

Comment: `std::io::fs::readdir`

Answer (score 262):

Use [`std::fs::read_dir()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_dir.html). Here's [an example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=27b48c9bb7e4905a7d3fb19f6c5de148&version=beta&backtrace=0):

```
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let paths = fs::read_dir("./").unwrap();

    for path in paths {
        println!("Name: {}", path.unwrap().path().display())
    }
}
```

It will simply iterate over the files and print out their names.

Comment: wow, it even compiles the first time in Rust ;)

Comment: OP asked how to list files in a directory, where this answer describes how to list the entries in a directory (which may be symlinks or other directories).

Comment: paths have .is_file and .is_dir methods, to filter out just the files.

Answer (score 31):

You could also use [glob](https://docs.rs/glob/latest/glob/), which is expressly for this purpose.

```
extern crate glob;
use self::glob::glob;

let files:Vec<Path> = glob("*").collect();
```

Comment: This does not work anymore: ``the trait bound `[u8]: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied in `std::path::Path` (within `std::path::Path`, the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `[u8]`) [E0277]

`[u8]` does not have a constant size known at compile-time [E0277]

required because it appears within the type `std::path::Path` [E0277]

required by `std::vec::Vec` [E0277]``

Comment: Glob works fine for me, just use the example from the readme.

Comment: Using a glob for this seems excessive

Answer (score 21):

This can be done with [`glob`](https://crates.io/crates/glob). Try [this on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=4652440b67a050bf241f8e048cbc1d1e):

```
extern crate glob;
use glob::glob;
fn main() {
    for e in glob("../*").expect("Failed to read glob pattern") {
        println!("{}", e.unwrap().display());
    }
}
```

You may see the [source](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/glob/blob/master/src/lib.rs).

---

And for walking directories recursively, you can use the [`walkdir`](https://crates.io/crates/walkdir) crate ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=8270b743007aecbf826adf7e68e05367)):

```
extern crate walkdir;
use walkdir::WalkDir;
fn main() {
    for e in WalkDir::new(".").into_iter().filter_map(|e| e.ok()) {
        if e.metadata().unwrap().is_file() {
            println!("{}", e.path().display());
        }
    }
}
```

See also the [Directory Traversal](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/file/dir.html) section of *The Rust Cookbook*.

Answer (score 3):

Still a question I stumple across sometimes. Here are two pure rust solutions:

Quick and dirty - swallows all errors, worst case = empty vec:

```
fn recurse(path: impl AsRef<Path>) -> Vec<PathBuf> {
    let Ok(entries) = read_dir(path) else { return vec![] };
    entries.flatten().flat_map(|entry| {
        let Ok(meta) = entry.metadata() else { return vec![] };
        if meta.is_dir() { return recurse(entry.path()); }
        if meta.is_file() { return vec![entry.path()]; }
        vec![]
    }).collect()
}
```

The slightly longer, error propagating version:

```
fn recurse_files(path: impl AsRef<Path>) -> std::io::Result<Vec<PathBuf>> {
    let mut buf = vec![];
    let entries = read_dir(path)?;

    for entry in entries {
        let entry = entry?;
        let meta = entry.metadata()?;

        if meta.is_dir() {
            let mut subdir = recurse_files(entry.path())?;
            buf.append(&mut subdir);
        }

        if meta.is_file() {
            buf.push(entry.path());
        }
    }

    Ok(buf)
}
```

Comment: You'll need ... `use std::{fs::read_dir, path::{Path, PathBuf}};`