# Efficient approach to get all logical drive letters of HDD and collect root dirs

Tags: winapi, rust

I am aware that there is a crate for similar tasks, but it is not Windows-specific and may not be the most efficient approach. I also wish to learn how to implement what I already know how to do in C# with Rust.

This is what I have tried so far: [read_dir source](http://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.4/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/std/fs/fn.read_dir.html) <sub>(updated)</sub>

```
fn main() {

    unsafe{
        for mut cur_drl in get_win32_ready_drives(){
            let mut mcur_drl = cur_drl.clone();
            let mut cur_path = PathBuf::from(mcur_drl);

            //here i try to print root of current logical
            let unwrpd_curfspath = fs::metadata(cur_path).unwrap();
            if unwrpd_curfspath.is_dir(){
                for entry in (fs::read_dir(cur_path)) {
                    let curfspath2 = fs::metadata(entry.path()).unwrap();
                    if curfspath2.is_dir(){

                        cur_drl.push_str(entry.path());
                        println!("drive {0}", cur_drl);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} 
// this is the working part of the project so far 
// getting all drive letters
//(hdd only actually (3 is hdd & 2 = removable..sd cards etc') into a list 
unsafe fn get_win32_ready_drives() -> Vec<String>
{
    let mut logical_drives = Vec::with_capacity(5);
    let mut bitfield =kernel32::GetLogicalDrives();
     let mut drive = 'A';
     let mut rtstr = CString::new("");

     while bitfield != 0 {
           if bitfield & 1 == 1 {

            let strfulldl = drive.to_string() + ":\\";
            let cstrfulldl = CString::new(strfulldl.clone()).unwrap();
            let drvT = kernel32::GetDriveTypeA(cstrfulldl.as_ptr());
            if(drvT ==3 || drvT ==2)
            {
                  logical_drives.push(strfulldl);
                  // println!("drive {0} is {1}", strfdl, drvT);
            }
           }
           drive = std::char::from_u32((drive as u32) + 1).unwrap();
                   bitfield >>= 1;
       }
    logical_drives
}
```

This code does not compile as I am having issues 
understanding each return type and how to properly handle iterating on its results.

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks. and `read_dir` source is coming from http://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.2/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/std/fs/fn.read_dir.html

Comment: I'd encourage you to [edit] your question to add that link. I'd also add a link to the crate that you mention to help future people solve their problem without needing to rewrite the code for learning purposes. Also, that doc links to Rust 1.2, while 1.4 is the current stable version.

Comment: Also, your question is muddled with separate issues. You seem to be asking about a concrete problem getting something to compile. You should reduce your code to produce an [MCVE](/help/mcve) that focuses on that specific problem. Once you have working code, you may want to ask on [Code Review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) for feedback on making things more efficient.

Comment: @Shepmaster you were right, now I'm here looking for a crate that can list drives, and nothing relevant but this question turns up :/

Answer (score 3):

with little help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076005/how-can-i-list-files-of-a-directory-in-rust)

```
extern crate kernel32;
extern crate libc;
use std::fs::{self, DirEntry};
use std::path::Path;
use std::path::PathBuf;.
fn main() {

    unsafe{
        for mut cur_drl in get_win32_ready_drives(){
            let mut mcur_drl = cur_drl.clone();
            let mut cur_path = PathBuf::from(mcur_drl.clone());

            //print root of each logical drive letter 
            let unwrpd_curfspath = fs::metadata(cur_path).unwrap();
            if unwrpd_curfspath.is_dir(){

                for entry in fs::read_dir(mcur_drl).unwrap() {

                        println!("drive {0}", entry.unwrap().path().display());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//getting all drive letters 
unsafe fn get_win32_ready_drives() -> Vec<String>
{
    let mut logical_drives = Vec::with_capacity(5);
    let mut bitfield =kernel32::GetLogicalDrives();
     let mut drive = 'A';
     let mut rtstr = CString::new("");

     while bitfield != 0 {
           if bitfield & 1 == 1 {

            let strfulldl = drive.to_string() + ":\\";
            let cstrfulldl = CString::new(strfulldl.clone()).unwrap();
            let x = kernel32::GetDriveTypeA(cstrfulldl.as_ptr());
            if(x ==3 || x ==2)
            {
                  logical_drives.push(strfulldl);
                  // println!("drive {0} is {1}", strfdl, x);
            }
           }
           drive = std::char::from_u32((drive as u32) + 1).unwrap();
                   bitfield >>= 1;
       }
    logical_drives
}
```

i hope that some other newbs could make use of this