# How can I remove files with a specific file extension in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-macros

I need to remove all the files with ".html" extension from a specific directory in Rust.

Do you have any ideas of how can I do that?

Comment: List files then remove the ones whose extension is "html" ? What specific step is a problem ? SO isn't supposed to write all the code for you and the functions are well documented in https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076005/how-can-i-list-files-of-a-directory-in-rust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 parts to removing a file:

1. Finding the file
2. Removing the file

You can easily find the file in Rust by iterating over every file in a directory and checking the extension, like so:

```rust
use std::fs;

for path in fs::read_dir("/path/to/dir").unwrap() {
    let path = path.unwrap().path();
    let extension = path.extension().unwrap();
}
```

Now you can use `extension` to do whatever you want, for example check if it's `html` and remove the file, like so:

```rust
use std::ffi::OsStr;
if extension == OsStr::new("html") {
    fs::remove_file(path).unwrap();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7d820fbd953bb7b87faf285a177f7fff) (not to actually run it, but to show the full code)

---

Alternatively, you can use a crate like [glob](https://docs.rs/glob/0.3.0/glob/) to make your life easier. Using `glob` makes your code this:

```rust
use glob::glob;
for path in glob("/path/to/dir/*.html").unwrap() {
    match path {
        Ok(path) => {
            println!("Removing file: {:?}", path.display());
            std::fs::remove_file(path);
        },
        Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e);
    }
}
```

[glob wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) for if you don't know what a glob is

Comment: Thank you a lot. I used the globe crate and it worked :)