# Existing command errors when invoked from Rust

Tags: rust, command

I am new to Rust and I was trying to run the Windows "dir" command via Rust. However, when I do run the program, it outputs an Err and says the program is not found.

My main function is,

```
// gsync app
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let res = Command::new("dir").output();
    println!("{:?}", res);
}
```

The output is,

```
   Compiling note v0.1.0 (C:\Users\Kavin\ultron\note)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.38s
     Running `target\debug\note.exe`
Err(Error { kind: NotFound, message: "program not found" })
```

what am I doing wrong?! Thank you for helping out.

Comment: AFAIK `dir` is not an executable, it is instead a builtin command in `cmd.exe` and as such cannot be called directly. Try with: `Command::new ("cmd").args (&[ "/C", "dir" ])`

Comment: Oh, got it. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: In case you really want to call `dir` and don't just use this as an example, there is a buit-in function for that in Rust which should work much more reliable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076005/how-can-i-list-files-of-a-directory-in-rust

Comment: @Finomnis I was using this as an example. But thanks for the info, it'll come in handy.