# Very simple Rust test failing with a panic

Tags: rust

I recently picked up Command-Line Rust by Ken Youens-Clark and on page 8 as he's going through how unit tests work in Rust he gives the following example of a test;

```
use std::process::Command;

#[test]
fn runs() {
    let mut cmd = Command::new("ls");
    let res = cmd.output();
    assert!(res.is_ok());
}
```

He says to run `cargo test` and verify that you get a passing test in the output, however, when I run the test it fails with the following message;

```
assertion failed: res.is_ok()
thread 'runs' panicked at tests\cli.rs:7:5:
```

Can someone explain why this test is failing for me? When I mucked around with it and changed the `let mut cmd = Command::new("ls");` line to have the name of my package instead of "ls" the test passes.

Comment: Print the error and see what it says.

Comment: Tip: Tests can return `Result` and will fail if they return `Err`, so you can do [something like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c0c19da2ee78bbeff08cd09533415374) and if the test fails you'll see a helpful explanation. Alternatively, you can [`.unwrap()` the `Result`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c6491a8db38f7bd946d3844863374e61).

Comment: The error is likely due to not having the `ls` command on your system.  Are you running in Windows perhaps?  If so, try `dir` instead

Comment: @MarkH `dir` isn't a proper binary though, is it? I thought it was a cmd built-in.

Comment: @cdhowie thank you!  Yes, that would have been out of the frying pan and into the fire.  [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73329872/existing-command-errors-when-invoked-from-rust) a SO topic demonstrating how to run "dir", if that's what OP actually wants.  Otherwise, any executable in the path would do.

Comment: @MarkH I am on windows, but 'ls' is a command in powershell which is the shell that I was running 'cargo test' from. I was able to get a form of this test running with that topic you linked though so many thanks for that.